# Does vscode have a csproj generator?

Tags: c#, batch-file, msbuild, visual-studio-code, csc

I am using Visual Studio Code because it is more lightweight than Visual Studio but still gives me the intellisense. However I could not find a way for Code to build a .csproj or .sln automatically, so I have been making the files by scratch. There is little documentation on it so I had to go off of examples from other files. It was all good and fine, but recently I hit a snag where compiling it with msbuild does not give me the same result as compiling by csc.exe. I would get a BadImageFormatException whenever I would load in a dll and try and use one of it's classes. My question is, is there a way to have vscode generate a csproj or sln file as I create new projects? And if there isn't, is there a way around having to make the csproj files I have compile in the same fashion as I do with the batch files?

csproj file:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="Splicer.dll">
        <HintPath>Splicer.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="DirectShowLib-2005.dll">
        <HintPath>DirectShowLib-2005.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Compile Include="src\*.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="Build">
    <MakeDir Directories="$(OutputPath)"
        Condition="!Exists('$(OutputPath)')"
    />
    <Csc
        Platform="x86"
        NoWarn=""
        Sources="@(Compile)"
        OutputAssembly="$(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).exe"
    />
</Target>
<PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyName>SplicerDemo</AssemblyName>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

Batch Compiler:

```
@echo off
set "CSC=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe"
set "Refs=Splicer.dll,DirectShowLib-2005.dll"
set "Files=src\SplicerDemo\*.cs"
set "Compile=%csc% /platform:x86 /r:%Refs% /out:SplicerDemo.exe /t:exe %Files$"
cmd
```

File to Compile:

```
using Splicer.Renderer;
using Splicer.Timeline;

using System.Drawing;

namespace SplicerDemo   {
    public class Start  {
        // Variables
        public string   outputFile;

        public Start()  {
            outputFile= "Foo.avi";
        }

        public static void Main()   {
            Start   s=  new Start();

            System.Console.WriteLine("Starting Build...");
            s.save();
            System.Console.WriteLine("Build Finished!");
        }

        // --- Methods ---

        public void save()  {
            // Variables
            DefaultTimeline timeline=   new DefaultTimeline(24);
            IGroup  _group= timeline.AddVideoGroup(32, 1024, 786);
            ITrack  vtrack= _group.AddTrack();
            ITrack  atrack= timeline.AddAudioGroup().AddTrack();
            Bitmap  img=    new Bitmap("image3.jpg");

            vtrack.AddImage("image1.jpg", 0, 24);
            vtrack.AddImage("image2.jpg", 0, 24);
            vtrack.AddImage(img, 0, 100);
            vtrack.AddImage("image1.jpg", 0, 128);

            atrack.AddAudio("audio1.mp3", 0, vtrack.Duration);

            using(AviFileRenderer renderer= new AviFileRenderer(timeline, outputFile))  {
                renderer.Render();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately VSCode doesn't have way to create/build solutions/projects targeting full .Net Framework however it does have support for projects targeting .Net Core. You can use [Yeoman](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/yeoman) project scaffolding system to create and build projects targeting .Net Core.

Answer (score 1):

The new C# Dev Kit extension from Microsoft will create .sln and .csproj files for you.

[Detailed instructions are here, currently](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/csharp/get-started), but here's the quick version:

Install the [C# Dev Kit extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dotnettools), then follow the instructions from the docs, above:

> 1. Bring up the Command Palette using ⇧⌘P and then type ".NET".
> 2. Find and select the .NET: New Project command.
> 3. After selecting the command, you'll need to choose the project template. Choose Console app.
> 4. To run your app, select Run > Start Debugging in the upper menu, or use the F5 keyboard shortcut.

Interface is kinda mvp right now, but it works.